# Is there a way I can loop over this and speed it up

Tags: r, function

I have a some data with month and sales. Is there way I can loop over all the months and get the mean

I'm not sure how to do this still very new at R

```
 df2 <- df[grep("Jan", df$Month),]
 mean(df2$Sales)
```

Rather than typing each month every time. Is there a way I can just get R to loop over all the months and give a mean for each month

Comment: it's hard, but u need something like that `library(dplyr)

df %>%
 filter(grepl("Jan", Month)) %>%
 group_by (Month) %>%
 summarize(mean_sales = mean(Sales))`

Comment: `with(df, tapply(Sales, Month, mean))` might work, but seeing he result of `dput(head(df))` would make answering the question easier

Comment: for(m in month.abb){df2 <- df[grep(m, df$Month),]
 print(paste(m, mean(df2$Sales), sep=" "))}